# Email form in footer to disappear after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im new to .Net MVC, and im for learning purposes making a simple e-mail newsletter signup form in my footer.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("details", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label class="margin20">Sign up for newsletter</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Email, new { id = "input1", Class = "form-control", Style = "display:inline-block; max-width:200px", Placeholder = "Example@Example.com", type = "email" })
        <button type="submit" disabled class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline-block" id="emailSignup">Signup</button>
    </div>
}
```

Currently the form works just fine (I can type in my email, and i receive a confirmation mail after submitting).

When the user submits the email, the user is redirected to another page. However, i want this form to work on the same page, so that after the submit button is pressed, it says something like "thank you for subscribing" instead of moving to new view.

Im thinking, that the easy way to come around this would be to make a jQuery script that hides the email form and unhides a div that says "Thank you for signing up"

However, i want to do this in MVC manners, so what would be "most" correct to do? `@RenderSection` could be an option i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, it's done with simple flags, based on the model state - i.e. whether the e-mail has been sent or not.  For example (very rough code);

```
@if (emailHasBeenSent)
{
    <div class="polite-message"> Thanks for signing up! </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="form-group form-inline"> your sign up code </div>
}
```

I'm fairly new to MVC too, but this is what I've seen from other people's code at work!

Comment: thats genius. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JeppeChristensen make sure you accept the answer if it works for you!

Comment: I'm sure people with more experience can suggest better ways, but thanks!